# What's a proper way to implement delete all option on a basic index form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users that have posts.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>                                                                                                                                                                                  

<h1>Listing Posts</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                         

<table>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  <thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    <tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      <th>Comment</th>                                                                                                                                                                                            
      <th colspan="3"></th>                                                                                                                                                                                       
    </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  </thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                        

  <tbody>                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>                                                                                                                                                                             
      <tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        <td><%= post.content %></td>                                                                                                                                                                           
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>                                                                                                                                                                   
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>                                                                                                                                                
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>                                                                                                           
      </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    <% end %>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  </tbody>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
</table>                                                                                                                                                                                                          

<br>                                                                                                                                                                                                              

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_user_post_path %>
```

And in controller

```
 def destroy                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    @user = @post.user                                                                                                                                                                                         
    @post.destroy                                                                                                                                                                                              
    respond_to do |format|                                                                                                                                                                                        
      format.html { redirect_to user_posts_url(@user), notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }                                                                                                         
      format.json { head :no_content }                                                                                                                                                                            
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  end
```

What's the proper way to implement a link and controller action to destroy all posts for a particular user?

**Edit:** 
config/routes.rb

```
resources :users do 
  resources :posts, shallow: true 
end
```

Edit 2:

```
 resources :users do                                                                                                                                                                                             
    #resources :posts, shallow: true                                                                                                                                                                           
    resources :posts, shallow: true do                                                                                                                                                                         
      delete :destroy_all, on: collection                                                                                                                                                                         
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  end
```

gives `no block given (yield)` error

aww my bad.. Just found the error.. forgot to add : to collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass an array of `post` IDs *only* if selected posts need to be deleted. If you want to delete *all* posts for a *particular* user, then here's how I would approach it:

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
    delete :destroy_all, on: :collection
  end
end
```

Here, `on: :collection` means that the route applies to the *collection* of posts; the route therefore looks like this:

`/users/:user_id/posts/destroy_all`

You can read more about adding member and collection routes in the Rails Guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
def destroy_all
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  user.posts.destroy_all
  # redirect somewhere
end
```

**app/views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to(
  "Delete all posts!", 
  destroy_all_user_posts_path, 
  method: :delete
) %>
```

If you want to delete all posts for the `current_user`, modify like so:

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
  delete :destroy_all, on: :collection
end
```

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
def destroy_all
  current_user.posts.destroy_all
  # redirect somewhere
end
```

**app/views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to(
  "Delete all posts!", 
  destroy_all_posts_path, 
  method: :delete
) %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please explain what  delete :destroy_all, on: :collection means?

Comment: `delete` means that route is for a DELETE request. `:destroy_all` is a custom route for deleting multiple items — you could call it whatever you like, just make sure you define a method with the same name in your controller. `on: :collection` means that the route applies to the collection of the resource. See my updated answer for more info.

Comment: What if I also wanted to include shallow?


I get no block given (yield) error for some reason. Check out EDIT #2

Comment: change `resources :posts` to `resources :posts, shallow: true do`

Comment: I did.. it gives me an error. Check out my edit #2 in original post

Comment: Never mind! Found the error.. I forgot to add colon : to my collection

Comment: In this case if I want to delete a certain comment through console I would do curl call of curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/comments/1         What would be the curl call to delete all the comments from post id 3 for example?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate controller method that accepts an array of post ids.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def destroy_all                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  posts = Post.where(:id => params[:post_ids])
  posts.delete_all                                                                                                                                                                                    
  redirect_to :back                                                                                                                                                                                                         
end
```

You will also need to supply the ids to the view method.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  ...
  @posts_ids = Post.find(... how ever you need to select all posts...).pluck(:id)
  ...
end
```

**views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
...
<%= link_to destroy_all_posts_path(:post_ids => @posts_ids), :method => :destroy %>
...
```

You will also need to supply the route.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
    delete :destroy_all
  end
end
```

And that should be it :)

Comment: so if my current routes are
 resources :users do                                                                                                                                                                                             
    resources :posts, shallow: true                                                                                                                                                                            
  end

Comment: See my edit. You don't need the `shallow: true` you are going more than two deep. If you are nesting more than once, then it is a best practice to use shallow.

Comment: so we are specifying a custom delete crud command with  delete :destroy_all referencing our function? or how does that work?

Comment: Yes, we create a custom route. You could also amend your `destroy` controller method to delete multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def destory_posts(user)
 user.posts.destroy_all
 render :nothing => true
end
```

add this method to your `routes` file. 
Create a link like `destory_posts_path(current_user)` from where you want to delete the posts.